# Drawing curved lines in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Is it possible to draw curved lines in canvas by their equations? If so, how? Let's say that I have math equation y=0,5*x^2 , how to print equation's graph?

I tried using `bezierCurveTo` and `quadraticCurveTo` methods unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to populate the array of points, then use `moveTo` and `lineTo` to draw it. Something like this

```
var x1 = 0; // Minimum x
var x2 = 10; // Maximum x
var xstep = 0.1; // How smooth the curve should be
// ctx is the context object
// You may want to apply some transformations to the coordinate system
for (var x = x1; x < x2; x += xstep) {
    var y = 0.5 * x * x;
    if (x == x1) { 
         ctx.moveTo(x, y); // First point
    } else {
         ctx.lineTo(x, y); // Subsequent points
    }
}

ctx.stroke();
```

`bezierCurveTo`, `quadraticCurveTo`, and the like have fixed equation form. I am not sure if they can be used to draw parabolas, but arbitrary curves are out of question.

Comment: +1 for nice and concise answer. BTW, `quadraticCurveTo` can generate a parabola if the middle control point is tangent to the midpoint of the starting and ending control points. `bezierCurveTo` acts identically to a quadratic curve if its 2 middle control points are set to the same point.